# "Speaking of/talking of" - similarities and differences

Tags: expressions

I was told that "speaking of" should refer to a previously mentioned subject and should trigger a change of the subject. For example:

> - Are you going to chip in on a joint gift for Frank? He has a birthday tomorrow.
> - Do I have to?
> - You don't have to if you don't feel like doing so.
> - Well, I feel like smoking now... but **speaking of chipping in**, I will chip in 10 dollars. (WRONG)

I was told that "speaking of chipping in" is not used correctly here because it continues the discussion of the previous subject. It would be OK if it started a new subject slightly related to the matter of chipping in. For example:

> - Well, I feel like smoking now... but **speaking of chipping in**, who even made it up? Isn't it just another useless concept?

Now I wonder what if I used "talking of chipping in"? Would it be OK to continue with the subject mentioned earlier in that case?

> - Are you going to chip in on a joint gift for Frank? He has a birthday tomorrow.
> - Do I have to?
> - You don't have to if you don't feel like doing so.
> - Well, I feel like smoking now... but **TALKING of chipping in**, I will chip in 10 dollars. (CORRECT? or WRONG?)

Comment: I don't think so. I think it has the same restrictions as 'speaking of'. I would prefer something like 'as for' or 'regarding' [formal] or 'about' [somewhat informal].

Answer (score 1):

Both 'speaking of...' and 'talking of...' introduce a new subject *related to* the previous one.

Suppose two of you have been talking about a work colleague, which reminds you of another colleague who has been ill. You might say "Speaking of [your workplace], have you heard how Joe Bloggs is?"

Comment: What expression would you recommend using if the speaker wants to dwell on the same subject and elaborate on it?

Comment: If the other person has changed the subject but you want to say more about the previous one, you might say "Going back to X..." or "To revert to X..."

Comment: I see. What if the interlocuter hasn't changed the subject as in my context. But the speaker themself veered off the subject a bit and then want to revert to it. Would "Going back to X..." or "To revert to X..." work? "Going back to chipping in, I will chip 10 dollars in"? Correct?

Comment: Yes, the same applies (but 'I will chip in 10 dollars' as you originally wrote).